# There is no "Hosting Content with Apple" section on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I create a new IAP item this way:

- click "Manage In-App Purchases"
- click "Create New"
- Select "Non-Consumable"

The section "Hosting Content with Apple" is not present for that app, or any of my apps for that matter.

If I log-in with a different developer account and follow exactly the same steps, there is a section "Hosting Content with Apple" Yes [] No [] for any/all apps.

Does Apple have yet a special policy I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you would have expired contracts in itunes connect. You should check about your paid app contracts in itunes.

Comment: That's not what is happening. There is a `Add Content` button, which allows me to create a new version. It reads `This In-App Purchase is not currently available for testing in the sandbox environment because you have chosen to host your content with Apple, but have not delivered your content. Upload your content to test this In-App Purchase in sandbox.`. It seems that somehow iTunes Connect or myself got confused during the creation of this IAP. The `Hosting Content with Apple` was never made available for this IAP. None of the other IAP exhibit this behavior.

Comment: As you have written this, I guess you had done some problems while creating IAP. There is an option Hosting content with apple and you should set it to NO. By mistake you would have set it to YES and that is why it causes the problems for you. Try creating another IAP with this and you will be good to go.

Comment: The solution *"Creating another IAP"* is what I eventually did, but I could only do so *after my app was approved* for that Developer account. But I never solved the original question: until my app was approved, **The section "Hosting Content with Apple" is not present for that app**. That section was missing, entirely. Hence my concern: "Does Apple have yet a special policy I am not aware of?". Creating the very same IAP using a different Developer account did not yield the same results. I am guessing that your response is most likely accurate.