# There is no “Hosting Content with Apple” section on iTunes Connect for my iTunes account

Tags: ios

**I create a new IAP item this way:**

```
click "Manage In-App Purchases"
click "Create New"
Select "Free-Subscription"
```

The section "Hosting Content with Apple" is not present for that app, or any of my apps for that matter.

If I log-in with a different developer account and follow exactly the same steps, there is a section "Hosting Content with Apple" Yes [] No [] for any/all apps.

Does Apple have yet a special policy I am not aware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is no "Hosting Content with Apple" section on iTunes Connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846679/there-is-no-hosting-content-with-apple-section-on-itunes-connect)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" in iTunes connect?
Maybe, Some you don't agree Contracts exist.